# CDF of multivariate normal distribution with hierarchical variation

Tags: probability, integration

I am trying to calculate $$\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}\left(\int_{a_{n}}^{b_{n}}\cdots\int_{a_{1}}^{b_{1}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\mu\right)^{2}}dx_{1}\cdots dx_{n}\right)d\mu$$  Is it possible to get a closed-form solution? Is it possible to even get a closed-form solution for what I enclosed in parentheses? If not, would it be a bad idea to approximate $e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\mu\right)^{2}}
 $ with a multivariate Taylor expansion and then integrate?

I may be using the term "closed-form" incorrectly here.  I realize the answer will contain error functions.

Comment: I think there's a way forward if the inner integrals (the ones on xi) have ranges from -Inf to Inf, but otherwise, in general I don't think the inner integrals have closed form solutions. (This is why Gaussian CDFs can't be written in closed forms)

Comment: Yeah, if the inner integral ranges were infinite, then this would be an easy problem.  I'd actually be happy with error functions in the solution.  There is an expression with error functions for the parenthetical expression when n=2.

Comment: $$(2\pi\sigma^2)^{n/2}\int_{-\alpha}^\alpha\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\Phi((b_i-\mu)/{}{}{}{}\sigma)-\Phi((a_i-\mu)/\sigma)\right)\,d\mu$$

Comment: I don't know why I didn't generalize that from n=2.  Is there any way to do that last integral with $\mu$?  If not, how does one *know* that?  How does one know when to quit?